# What is a django way to do multiple select input with repeatable values that preserve order of selection?

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, post

I am currently working on a Django project which has a form that will be populated with dynamic values (django models). The form will allow the user to select multiple values, (and select them more than once). The user will then be able to modify their selection by arranging the elements in any order they choose.

Looking at Django's backend, it seems that there is no direct way to do this. Using Django models and fields, I could design something that links models using foreign keys. However, because I need to support duplicate values, I will be copying references multiple times. Also, this makes modifying data expensive.

Is there a way to do this other than relying heavily on client side jQuery to generate a dynamic form, and then saving the form values into a database as comma separated values or a list? I would like to use Django's provided tools as much as possible.

Comment: Your question is not clear (in terms of input) but I suspect an intermediate table is what you are looking for:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: There's no problem with "copying references multiple times" if that's what you need.. how else would you be able to do this? There aren't many ways to store user selections: `1,1,2,1,1`. Just build the models to store that information. It's not going to be possible for us to weigh the pros and cons of CSV vs DB in your particular use case.